# Maximum average distance between two numbers across multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance

Let's say you have `k` arrays of size `N`, each containing unique values from `1` to `N`.

How would you find the two numbers that are on average the furthest away from each other?

For example, given the arrays:

```
[1,4,2,3]
[4,2,3,1]
[2,3,4,1]
```

Then the answer would be item `1` and `2`, because they are of distance 2 apart in the first two arrays, and 3 numbers apart in the last one.

I am aware of an O(kN^2) solution (by measuring the distance between each pair of numbers for each of the `k` arrays), but is there a better solution?

I want to implement such an algorithm in C++, but any description of a solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a linear-time transformation indexing the numbers, this problem boils down to computing the diameter of a set of points with respect to L1 distance. Unfortunately this problem is subject to the curse of dimensionality.

Given

```
    1 2 3 4
1: [1,4,2,3]
2: [4,2,3,1]
3: [2,3,4,1]
```

we compute

```
    1 2 3
1: [1,4,4]
2: [3,2,1]
3: [4,3,2]
4: [2,1,3]
```

and then the L1 distance between `1` and `2` is `|1-3| + |4-2| + |4-1| = 8`, which is their average distance (in problem terms) times `k = 3`.

That being said, you can apply an approximate nearest neighbor algorithm using the input above as the database and the image of each point in the database under `N+1-v` as a query.

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=QKVY4mDivBEC&lpg=PA257&ots=JyZg1BhdSF&dq=algorithm%20L1%20diameter&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q=algorithm%20L1%20diameter&f=false) reference suggests a randomized algorithm with expected linear runtime which may be of interest to the OP.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Could be useful, but for low dimensions only.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to combine this with a heuristical approach described in another answer?

Comment: @MagnusE-F There are a lot of approximate nearest neighbor algorithms out there. I amended my answer for how to reduce this problem to ANN.

Answer (score 1):

I've a suggestion *for the best case*. You can follow an heuristical approach.

For instance, You know that if `N=4`, `N-1=3` will be the maximum distance and `1` will be the minimum. The mean distance is `10/6=1,66667`  (sums of distances among pairs within array / number of pairs within an array).

Then, you know that if two numbers are on the edges for `k/2` arrays (most of the times), it is already on the average top (>= `2` of distance), even if they're just `1` distance apart in the other `k/2` arrays. That could be a solution for a best case in `O(2k)` = `O(k)`.

Comment: That seems like a good approach. In my case N is much larger than k and I think a heuristic algorithm will perform well

Comment: What about the worst case of this algorithm? Is it still O(k N^2)?

Comment: @JérômeRichard we didn't change the algorithm, we just added a heuristic that, if applies, applies only to a good scenario. In a worst case, the main algorithm will solve it.